# How to change a class when one of the elements classname change?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this menu of elements, what is the best approach to change the last  div element from hidden to visible when one of the elements with class closed changes to open using Jquery, What i want is when i click on one of the li and change it from closed to , i want to change the dynamic ul to display none or block, do i need to loop over all the elements and check their class?

```html
<ul class="groupmenu">
 <li class="closed"></li>
  <ul class="level1"></ul>
 <li class="closed"></li>
  <ul class="level1"></ul>
 <li class="closed"></li>
  <ul class="level1"></ul>
 <li class="closed"></li>
  <ul class="level1"></ul>
 <li class="closed"></li>
  <ul class="level1"></ul>
 <li class="closed"></li>
  <ul class="level1"></ul>
 <li class="closed"></li>
  <ul class="level1"></ul>
 <li class="closed"></li>
  <ul class="level1"></ul>
 <li class="closed"></li>
  <ul class="level1"></ul>
 <li class="closed"></li>
</ul>
<div class="dynamic hidden"></div>
```

Comment: Did you intend to have the invalid HTML, or are the `<li>` supposed to be wrapped around the "level1" `<ul>`?

Comment: No it should be like that cuz every ul.level1 has also its child elements but i just want to reduce the lines i'm typing

Comment: It’s not possible to give a sensible answer without legal HTML. Please correct that first so we know more about what you are really trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your `ul.level1` elements should be wrapped in `li` elements.

Then, on click of a `li.closed` element, you could :

- toggle the visibility of its `ul.level1` child element.
- toggle the visibility of your `div.dynamic` element using `!$("ul.level1:not(.hidden)").length`. It will return a boolean whose value will be `false` if there is at least 1 `ul.level1` element that does not have the `.hidden` class. Otherwise it will return `true`.

```js
$("li.closed").click(function() {
  $(this).find("ul.level1").toggleClass("hidden");
  $("div.dynamic").toggleClass("hidden",!$("ul.level1:not(.hidden)").length);
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="groupmenu">
 <li class="closed">
  ul closed
  <ul class="level1 hidden">
    <li>visible</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="closed">
  ul closed
  <ul class="level1 hidden">
    <li>visible</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="closed">
  ul closed
  <ul class="level1 hidden">
    <li>visible</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="closed">
  ul closed
  <ul class="level1 hidden">
    <li>visible</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
<div class="dynamic hidden">
  dynamic
</div>
```